# Paypal Reference Transaction

Tags: paypal, reference, transactions, e-commerce

I'm currently working on e-commerce website and I need to integrate it with paypal.

All I want to do is creating a billing agreement and obtaining billing agreement ID when new user signup for the website.

And to re-issue an invoice with the saved billing agreement ID when they get service.

But I'm getting following error when I call `SetExpressCheckout` API endpoint for creating a billing agreement.

```
 Merchant not enabled for reference transactions
```

Some people says, even I'm working on sandbox account, I need to ask paypal to provide reference transaction. And I don't know how.

Please tell me what I have to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about managing a Paypal account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be informed that even for Sandbox, you need to request the PayPal Merchant Technical Support team to enable it.You can provide your PayPal Sandbox Email address.
I can enable reference Transaction for your Sandbox account.

Or

You can create a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! The Sandbox email address I'm working with is danial.agus88@gmail.com. How may I get notified when you enable reference Transaction?

Comment: I see that you have a Personal - Unverified PAyPal account.
You need to have a business account to enable reference transactions.

Comment: I created a developer account on paypal. It's associated with the above email address. And the sandbox business username which is generated by paypal) is danial.agus88-facilitator_api1.gmail.com.

Comment: I hve enabled `Reference transaction` for this account :danial.agus88-facilitator@gmail.com. You can try to run SetExpressCheckout  and see if you get the error message "Merchant not enabled for reference transactions" to check.

Comment: Hi, Vimal, Thank you! Now I got SUCCESS result. Thank you

Comment: Oh, I forgot to accept the answer. I'm sorry that I can't make a vote up, because of rack of my reputation. I'll, if I'll get enough reputation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Vimal. I need your help again. This time is production account. My code works perfectly for sandbox account, but not working for production account. Production server returns 10002 error "Security header is not valid".

Comment: I double checked the merchant account info, but there is no problem with that. Please give me advise. Thank you.

Comment: this is caused when you have wrong  API endpoints or the API credentials are incorrect(check if there are no spaces and correctly spelled) and see if you are pointing to LIVE endpoints

Comment: Hi, Vimal. I'm using a Angell Eye CodeIgniter library for paypal integration. Other developers don't have such a problem in both test and production integration. Adel.

Comment: please raise a ticket here : www.paypal.com/mts

Comment: @Vimalnath I'm getting the same problem. How can I enable  reference Transaction for my sand box email address. My email is vikas-`facilitator@esignature.com.np`
.Could you please enable reference Transaction for this account.Help will be appreciated .

Comment: @BibekSharma I have enabled.

Comment: @Vimalnath Thank you. You made my day
Would you please look into this.I'm new to paypal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945411/difference-between-channelinitiatedbilling-vs-merchantinitiatedbillingsingleagre

Comment: @Vimalnath I am facing the error, 

 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10209
 [L_ERRORCODE1] => 10004

Paypal team said that, RT enabled.  What to do?

Comment: @Vimalnath I have posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475113/call-to-doreferencetransaction-method-giving-error

Please look at it, suggest something that will help us.

Comment: @Vimalnath Can I have your email address please.Seriously I need your help.I'll be available in bs_chapagain@hotmail.com