# Difference between ChannelInitiatedBilling vs MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm trying to integrate paypal in a e-commerce site on rails.I'm working on a existing code.While going through code I found two types of `BillingType` on configuration file, I found teo types of `ChannelInitiatedBilling` and `MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement`.

What is the basic difference between them? Any appreciation will be appreciated.

## EDIT 1

While using `ChannelInitiatedBilling` I'm getting this error

> Channel not enabled for channel initiated billing.

While using `MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement` I'm getting this error

> Merchant not enabled for reference transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billing type is of two types :

MerchantInitiatedBilling : PayPal creates a billing agreement for each transaction associated with buyer

MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement : PayPal creates a single billing agreement for all transactions associated with buyer.

Do you have a link that supports `ChannelInitiatedBilling` ? May be its deprecated.

Comment: I'm using sharetribe(https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe). It says Paypal is not supported in open source version so after a lot of googling I found `MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement` . So I'm using it instead of `ChannelInitiatedBilling`

Comment: Please kindly have a look, I need your help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262762/using-api-calling-account-as-receiver-account

Comment: Hi @Vimalnath , would you please have a look here, really need your few words http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780148/paypal-preauthorized-adaptive-payment/38783123

Answer (score 1):

`ChannelInitiatedBilling` is actually working. I contacted PayPal and they said they have to enable this feature against the account you are using. Regardless of sandbox or live.
They said there is not document for ChannelInitiatedBilling at the moment.
I have had my accounts enabled and everything works well.
So, if you see `Channel not enabled for channel initiated billing.` message, contact PayPal to enable it for you.