# Paypal Preauthorized + Adaptive payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm working on an online marketplace built on Ruby On Rails where customer can book services from the provider.

**Existing flow:**
**(Preauthorize Only)**

Customer Authorize money **=>** Service provider provides the services **=>** Money will be capture to my account **=>** **I'm paying providers manually using their paypal email address.**

**What I want:** **(Preauthorize + Adaptive)**

Customer Authorize money **=>** Service provider provides the services **=>** Money will be capture to my account and **will split between Provider and us.**

I'm not sure if this is provided by the paypal or not.

It will be very difficult to go with existing system for the 000's transaction per day. So Is there any way to split payment while capturing, I've also implemented Adaptive payment using [active_paypal_adaptive_payment](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) but not sure is their any way to integrate it with the preauthorize payment.

Any suggestion will be appreciated,
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that.

Basically you will need to make a preapproval payment and then later do either a chained or parallel payment using the preapprova key.

Here you can find more information:

[Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Comment: Thanks bro, Really appreciated, 
I'll go through the link and come to you.