# call to DoReferenceTransaction method giving error

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am calling CreateBillingAgreement after SetExpressCheckout, both are successfull. BILLINGAGREEMENTID is returnd by CreateBillingAgreement.

This BILLINGAGREEMENTID  is passed as REFERENCEID to DoReferenceTransaction.

NVP is constructed as :

```
$nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&REFERENCEID=' . $billing_agreement_id . '&PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
    $nvpstr .= '&CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName .'&L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital'.'&DESC='.urlencode("Test Recurring Payment( $" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] . " monthly)");

    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=Digital";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test Name";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=".$_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];

    $nvpstr.="&L_NAME0=Test Name";
    $nvpstr.="&L_DESC0=".urlencode("Test Recurring Payment( $" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] . " monthly)");
    $nvpstr.="&L_AMT0=".$_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
    $nvpstr.="&L_QTY0=1";
```

call to DoReferenceTransaction method giving error:

```
  Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-11-02T10:20:06Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 3e60a1baba3b3
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 64
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10209
    [L_ERRORCODE1] => 10004
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Disabled
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE1] => Invalid Data
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Preapproved Payments not enabled.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE1] => This transaction cannot be processed.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE1] => Error
    [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => None
    [PAYMENTTYPE] => None
    [ORDERTIME] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    [PAYMENTSTATUS] => None
    [PENDINGREASON] => None
    [REASONCODE] => None
)
```

**Note:** Using Sandbox account for testing.

**UPDATE:**

```
function DoReferenceTransaction(){

    //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls   
    $token = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
    $paymentType = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
    $currencyCodeType = urlencode($_SESSION['currencyCodeType']);
    //$payerID = urlencode($_SESSION['payer_id']);  $_SESSION['billing_agreement_id']
     $billing_agreement_id = urlencode($_SESSION['billing_agreement_id']);  

$FinalPaymentAmt = urlencode( $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"]);
    $serverName = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    $nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&REFERENCEID=' . $billing_agreement_id . '&PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
    $nvpstr .= '&CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName .'&L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital'.'&DESC='.urlencode("Test Recurring Payment( $" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] . " monthly)");

    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=Digital";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test Name";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=".$_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];

    $nvpstr.="&L_NAME0=Test Name";
    $nvpstr.="&L_DESC0=".urlencode("Test Recurring Payment( $" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] . " monthly)");
    $nvpstr.="&L_AMT0=".$_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
    $nvpstr.="&L_QTY0=1";



    /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
      If an error occured, show the resulting errors
     */

        $resArray = hash_call("DoReferenceTransaction", $nvpstr);  
echo "<pre>";
   print_r($resArray); exit;

    /* Display the API response back to the browser.
      If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
      If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
     */
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

    return $resArray;
}
```

**NVP for DoReferenceTransaction:**

```
&TOKEN=EC-30M31870BS241854X&REFERENCEID=B-81S156104Y376273D&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=3&CURRENCYCODE=USD&IPADDRESS=paypalrecurring.com&L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital&DESC=Test+Recurring+Payment%28+%243+monthly%29&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=Digital&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test Name&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=3&L_NAME0=Test Name&L_DESC0=Test+Recurring+Payment%28+%243+monthly%29&L_AMT0=3&L_QTY0=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a live or a sandbox API call?

You need to have Reference Transaction activated on your PayPal account to be able to call this API.

The Reference Transaction API is not available for everybody. I would advise to contact your PayPal representative to ask them to activate this on your PayPal account.

If you are doing this on the sandbox, you should simply upgrade your sandbox account to a Pro account. This should activate Reference Transaction on the sandbox account.

To be sure, you should ask PayPal if your sandbox account has Reference Transaction enabled.

Can you send the full API call in your question please?

**Update**

I see something strange in your code:

```
$nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital";
$nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=Digital";
```

Change it by:

```
$nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Physical";
$nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1";
```

**Update 2**

I see few errors in the API call:

```
&TOKEN=EC-30M31870BS241854X&
REFERENCEID=B-81S156104Y376273D&
PAYMENTACTION=Sale&
AMT=3&
CURRENCYCODE=USD&
IPADDRESS=paypalrecurring.com&
L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital&
DESC=Test+Recurring+Payment%28+%243+monthly%29&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=Digital&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test Name&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=3&
L_NAME0=Test Name&
L_DESC0=Test+Recurring+Payment%28+%243+monthly%29&
L_AMT0=3&
L_QTY0=1string(606)
```

Provide a valid IP address in the IP address variable.

Replace

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=Digital&
```

by:

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&
```

In the last parameter there is a wrong parameter replace:

```
L_QTY0=1string(606)
```

by:

```
L_QTY0=1
```

Eventually change the item category from Digital to Physical. I know you need special rights to do Digital Goods with PayPal.

```
L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Physical&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Physical&
```

Comment: Paypal team said : RT enabled.

Comment: Try with a more recent version number. For example 105

Comment: [VERSION] => 64, which version need to use?

Comment: Hi, pralthom, how to know that RT is enabled in sandbox account?

Comment: If DoReferencTransaction is successful. As far as I know there is no other way.

Comment: I have checked with version 105, same ERROR.

Comment: Could you please add the full API call in your question? I'd like to see what you are posint

Comment: Could you print_r the $nvp_str?

Comment: Hi, pralthim, I have changed everything as you suggested. But still the error.

Comment: here is the updated post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493444/not-getting-success-for-doreferencetransaction/