# Not getting success for DoReferenceTransaction

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

See how I started complete procedure,

**Step 1.  First called SetExpressCheckout,**

```
AMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=0.00
PAYMENTACTION
BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION

BILLINGTYPE=MerchantInitiatedBilling

RETURNURL
CANCELURL
CURRENCYCODE



SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole 
LOCALECODE=us 
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

**step 2. then I called CreateBillingAgreement**

```
TOKEN
PAYERID
PAYMENTACTION

AMT
CURRENCYCODE
IPADDRESS
```

It returns Billing Id.

**Step 3. calling DoReferenceTransaction with parameters:**

```
&REFERENCEID=B-0GJ65589SA3528026   //billing Id generated by CreateBillingAgreement method
&PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&AMT=3.00
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&IPADDRESS=paypalrecurring.com
&L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
&DESC=Test+Recurring+Payment%28+%243.00+monthly%29
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test Name
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=3.00
&L_NAME0=Test Name
&L_DESC0=Test+Recurring+Payment%28+%243.00+monthly%29
&L_AMT0=3.00
&ITEMAMT=3.00
&L_QTY0=1
```

But the aerror ocuurs:

```
  Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-11-03T11:29:51Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 811b64f880aff
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 69
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10004
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Data
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => None
    [PAYMENTTYPE] => None
    [ORDERTIME] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    [PAYMENTSTATUS] => None
    [PENDINGREASON] => None
    [REASONCODE] => None
)
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.
**Note:** Paypal team said RT enabled. (Sandbox testing)

Answer (score 0):

First try to set

> RECURRING

field of DoReferenceTransaction API call.

If it's without success use method CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile instead DoReferenceTransaction. [API Documentation link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/).

I recommend to not use paypal sandbox - just use https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp and set price to 0.01 - this will prevent double testing

**Error 10004 has appear when has incompatibility between methods SetExpressCheckout and ( in your case ) DoReferenceTransaction**

**About error "Express Checkout Digital Goods is no longer available for new integrations" : 
We made a contact with Paypal support to activate the Digital Goods for our main paypal account. Also we tried many times to activate Digital Goods inside our paypal account and after several days this error disappear like a miracle :)**

**I am not so sure how I resolve this error but after trying many different tests ( including asking PayPal support ) he just disappear. So my advice is to continue trying with different ways and combinations**

Comment: Hi Pavel, We are in Development Phase, so want to still stay with Sandbox for now. The error is only 10004 now. 

This transaction cannot be processed.

Comment: there is limitation with variation of recurring amount in case of  CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, so I have decided to go with DoReferenceTransaction with Billing agreement. Please guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with DoReferenceTransaction but this error has appear when has incompatibility between methods SetExpressCheckout and ( in your case ) DoReferenceTransaction

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, what does it mean by:
** Express Checkout Digital Goods is no longer available for new integrations **

Comment: About error "Express Checkout Digital Goods is no longer available for new integrations" : We made a contact with Paypal support to activate the Digital Goods for our main paypal account. Also we tried many times to activate Digital Goods inside our paypal account and after several days this error disappear like a miracle :)

Comment: I am not so sure how I resolve this error but after trying many different tests ( including asking PayPal support ) he just disappear. So my advice is to continue trying with different ways and combinations

Comment: Recurring payments is different than Reference Transaction. The question is related to Reference Transaction.